# jQuery return checked="checked" in checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, concatenation

I want to put checked="checked" in specific checkboxes using jquery. I have built the code but is adding as "checked="checked" "="". How can I overcome this issue.

```
    function PMS_Checked(id){

        var str =  "12,14,15,16";

        if(str.indexOf(id) != -1){

        return "checked='checked'";

        }

    }
```

Her, I created the JSFiddle example.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kaf1evvz/)

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ok. let me update

Comment: Aside from the problem, I'd suggest changing your `str` variable to an array. Your current logic would check `11` if you have values of `111,112, 113` etc.

Comment: Thank @RoryMcCrossan, I update the question.

Comment: Please also include the code that actually calls this function.

Comment: where are you calling PMS_Checked and what are you passing as id

Comment: Please read the linked help page in Ele's comment.  We cannot help you if you are not going to provide enough code for us to replicate your error

Comment: I have updated the question. Thanks to all for their kind support.

Comment: @ZubairMushtaq please check my answer

Comment: @JPRLCol Yes, your answer is working. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in your input, you should remove the " once you call the function and make the concatenation, I changed a bit your code, so this is how you should have your input

```
<input type="checkbox" '+PMS_Checked(campus_id)+'name="teacher_faculty_meta[semester_id]['+campus_id+']" value="'+campus_id+'">
```

please check
you also you missed to return in the next code you function

```
return "checked='true'";
```

[sample](https://jsfiddle.net/0sd15ptf/)

Comment: Biggest part of this was changing `”checked=‘true’”` this is due to checked being a true/false attribute and thus `checked` is an invalid value to assign.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
function pms_checked(id) {
  var str = "12,13,14,15";
  if (str.indexOf(id) != -1)
    return 'Checked="Checked"';
}
```